# Commercial Media Foundation Filters

Tags: filter, h.264, codec, aac, ms-media-foundation

I was wondering if anybody knows a company that produces commercial Media Foundation MFTs, sinks and sources? Right now I am working with DirectShow but I would like to move on to Media Foundation. I am especially interested in AAC and H.264 decoders and encoders and a RTMP sink.

Thanks, David

Comment: `AAC` and `H.264` decoders are shipped with Windows (availability depends on Windows version). Some MF components are also available with Intel Media SDK http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-media-sdk/

Comment: But the problem is that I heard that these codecs are not allowed to be used in commercial application since Microsoft just licensed them for Windows

Comment: It is the case of Dolby Digital Audio Decoder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx See the MSDN page under "Important" there. And it just won't work with your app. MPEG-4 decoders (including AAC, H.264) are there in Windows to be a part of regular Windows services.

Comment: Do you know of a vendor offering an RTMP sink?

Comment: No, I am not aware of such. The whole `RTMP` is ridiculously unfriendly and confusing protocol. It might perhaps only be an option to wrap open source `librtmp` or `ffmpeg` into MF interface to implement a sink.

Comment: That sounds promising! Haven't thought of that option! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This company produces Media Foudnation codecs and de/muxes. Here is a link to their H264 codec: https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/h264

Answer (score 0):

Besides the system provided software AAC, and H.264 decoders. The graphics card venders also provide the Hardware ones for H.264 and even H.265, such as Intel, AMD and Nvidia.